# CURL: How to encode the url postfix

Tags: curl

We can do URL encoding of query string parameter in CURL with --data-urlencode &  -G. But 
is there any way to encode the  URL postfix e.g., there is a space in **"/Feature A"**

```
http://www.example.com/src/test/resources/Suites/ByFeature/Feature A?limit=100&at=develop
```

Comment: idk where you got that url from, but it's broken. that is *not* a valid url. problem lies at wherever you got that url from.

Comment: ```curl $(php -r 'echo strtr($argv[1],[" "=>"%20"]);' 'http://example.com/src/test/resources/Suites/ByFeature/Feature A?limit=100&at=develop')```